# Controller causing an internal error on swagger

Tags: c#, swagger-ui

For some reason this controller is messing up my swagger giving me an internal server error 500. When I disable it or remove it from project then swagger works just fine. I can't seem to find a reason why this isn't working. The wpi is working fine and swagger is setup correctly. Any ideas?

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations;
using WebApi.Data;
using WebApi.Models;
using WebApi.ActionFilters;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using WebApi.Helpers;

namespace WebApi.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ReleaseNotesController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public ReleaseNotesController(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        //GET: api/ReleaseNotes
        [HttpGet]
        [SwaggerOperation(Summary = "Get releaseNotes", Description = "List of available releaseNotes")]
        [SwaggerResponse(200, "Successful operation.")]
        public ActionResult<IEnumerable<ReleaseNote>> GetReleaseNote()
        {
            return _context.ReleaseNotes.FromSql(ReleaseNote.GetAllQuery()).ToList();
        }

        // GET: api/ReleaseNotes/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        [ServiceFilter(typeof(ValidateEntityExistsAttribute<ReleaseNote>))]
        [SwaggerOperation(Summary = "Get single releaseNote", Description = "Look for a specific releaseNote, filtering by ID.")]
        [SwaggerResponse(404, "No releaseNote was found for the provided ID.")]
        [SwaggerResponse(200, "Successful operation.")]
        public ActionResult<ReleaseNote> GetReleaseNote(int id)
        {
            var releaseNotes = _context.ReleaseNotes.FromSql(ReleaseNote.GetByIdQuery(id)).ToList();

            if (releaseNotes.Count == 0)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return releaseNotes.First();
        }

        private bool ReleaseNoteExists(int id)
        {
            return _context.ReleaseNotes.Any(e => e.Id == id);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add some error text?

Comment: {"StatusCode":500,"Message":"Internal Server Error. Check with Administrator"} that is all it gives me.